# How do I make startAnimating / activityImageView load quickly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

My apps first view controller is loading the code below which is sorta like `activityImageView` and well, you guessed it, it's slow! It may be because I am loading 304.jpg's to create a gif and or animation lol. Is there any way i can load this quickly? I find when I remove the jpgs down to around 10 - 50 jpgs, its loads like a bullet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
_Loading.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal1.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal2.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal3.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal4.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal5.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal6.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal7.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal8.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal9.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal10.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal11.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal12.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal13.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal14.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal15.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal16.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal17.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal18.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal19.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal20.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal21.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal22.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal23.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal24.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal25.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal26.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal27.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal28.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal29.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal30.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal31.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal32.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal33.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal34.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal35.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal36.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal37.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal38.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal39.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal40.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal41.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal42.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal43.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal44.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal45.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal46.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal47.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal48.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal49.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal50.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal51.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal52.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal53.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal54.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal55.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal56.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal57.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal58.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal59.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal60.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal61.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal62.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal63.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal64.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal65.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal66.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal67.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal68.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal69.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal70.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal71.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal72.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal73.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal74.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal75.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal76.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal77.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal78.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal79.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal80.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal81.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal82.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal83.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal84.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal85.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal86.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal87.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal88.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal89.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal90.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal91.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal92.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal93.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal94.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal95.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal96.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal97.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal98.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal99.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal100.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal102.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal103.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal104.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal105.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal106.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal107.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal108.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal109.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal110.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal111.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal112.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal113.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal114.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal115.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal116.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal117.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal118.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal119.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal120.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal121.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal122.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal123.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal124.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal125.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal126.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal127.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal128.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal129.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal130.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal131.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal132.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal133.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal134.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal135.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal136.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal137.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal138.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal139.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal140.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal141.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal142.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal143.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal144.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal145.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal146.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal147.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal148.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal149.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal150.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal151.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal152.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal153.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal154.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal155.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal156.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal157.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal158.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal159.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal160.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal161.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal162.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal163.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal164.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal165.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal166.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal167.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal168.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal169.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal170.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal171.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal172.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal173.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal174.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal175.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal176.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal177.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal178.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal179.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal180.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal181.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal182.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal183.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal184.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal185.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal186.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal187.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal188.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal189.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal190.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal191.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal192.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal193.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal194.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal195.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal196.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal197.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal198.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal199.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal200.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal201.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal202.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal203.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal204.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal205.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal206.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal207.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal208.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal209.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal210.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal211.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal212.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal213.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal214.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal215.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal216.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal217.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal218.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal219.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal220.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal221.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal222.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal223.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal224.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal225.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal226.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal227.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal228.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal229.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal230.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal231.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal232.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal233.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal234.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal235.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal236.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal237.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal238.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal239.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal240.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal241.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal242.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal243.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal244.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal245.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal246.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal247.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal248.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal249.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal250.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal251.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal252.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal253.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal254.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal255.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal256.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal257.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal258.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal259.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal260.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal261.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal262.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal263.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal264.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal265.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal266.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal267.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal268.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal269.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal270.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal271.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal272.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal273.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal274.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal275.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal276.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal277.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal278.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal279.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal280.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal281.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal282.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal283.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal284.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal285.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal286.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal287.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal288.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal289.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal290.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal291.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal292.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal293.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal294.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal295.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal296.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal297.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal298.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal299.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal300.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal301.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal302.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal303.jpg"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Signal304.jpg"],nil];


[_Loading startAnimating];
```

Comment: Would it be better to load the images externally?

Comment: Do you need to use images for the animation? Maybe you can do it using other means.

Comment: @maddy Unfortunately, yes. What 'other means' might you be talking about? :)

Comment: View animations, core animation, sprite kit, etc. There are many ways to do animations without using any images.

Comment: To animate images in UIImageView, you can use [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) which supports GIFs. It will reduce the pain of handling 304 image files and possibly result in better performance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a image with format is *.gif to process.

You can download a image with format is *.gif and show it on the your ViewController.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can research to see some frameworks support for you.
Ex: https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/